# Looking for a reference to a proof of $(I - A)^{-1} = I + A + A^2 + A^3 + \ldots$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, reference-request, matrix-calculus

On some online forum, there is the claim:

Given some square matrix:

$$(I - A)^{-1} = I + A + A^2 + A^3 + \ldots$$

> This is true if the right side converges, which is true if and only if
>   all of the eigenvalues of A have absolute value smaller than $1$.

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/matrix-inverse-equals-power-series.423897/

I really like this result, because it relies on the more intuitive spectral radius rather than matrix norm which is defined as:

\begin{align} \|A\| &= \sup\{\|Ax\| : x\in K^n \mbox{ with }\|x\|= 1\} \\ &= \sup\left\{\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} : x\in K^n \mbox{ with }x\ne 0\right\}. \end{align}

Can someone provide a reference to the proof of this claim?

Comment: Made me think of geometric series for a second...

Comment: One proof is given in Horn and Johnson's matrix analysis

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Found it pg 348

Comment: @BeachedWhale good.  Is that the new edition (with the colorful picture on the cover)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom 2nd edition

Comment: you can also find it in the form you stated as an exercise on page 7 of Bhatia's Matrix Analysis http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387948461

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also prove it by relating spectral radius with matrix norm.
For a linear operator $A$,
$$\operatorname{spr}(A) \le \|A\|$$
where
$$\begin{align}
\|A\| &= \underset{\|x\|=1}{\sup} \|Ax\| \\
\operatorname{spr}(A) &= \max\left\lbrace |\lambda|: \lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of } A \right\rbrace
\end{align}$$
 The spectral radius $\operatorname{spr}(A)$ and $\|A\|$ are equal iff the operator $A$ is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix).

So $\|A\| < 1 \Rightarrow \operatorname{spr}(A) < 1 \Rightarrow $ all of the eigenvalues of $A$ have absolute value smaller than 1.

See Exercise I.2.6 of [Rajendra Bhatia's Matrix Analysis](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387948461) where he calls it the [Neumann Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

See comments above: a proof is given on page 348 of Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson.

**Citation:** Horn, Roger A., and Charles R. Johnson. Matrix Analysis. 2nd ed. New York: Cambridge University Press, 2013, p 348