# $-\frac{d}{dt} \log \det(E_n-tA) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \mathrm{trace}(A^m)t^{m-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $A \in M \left( n\times n, \mathbb{C} \right)$ then

$$
-\frac{d}{dt} \log \det(E_n-tA) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \mathrm{trace}(A^m)t^{m-1}
$$

How do I show that the equation is true? Do I need something like *jordan normal form*?

Answer (score 1):

One can conjugate $A$ to put it in triangular form with diagonal elements
$a_1,\ldots,a_n$ say. Then
$$\det(A-tI)=(a_1-t)\cdots(a_n-t)$$
and logarithmic differentiation gives
$$-\frac d{dt}\det(A-tI)=\frac1{t-a_1}+\cdots+\frac1{t-a_n}.$$
This doesn't seem to correspond to your RHS though.

ADDED IN EDIT

If all $|a_i|<1$ then
$$\sum_1^\infty\text{trace}(A^m)t^{m-1}=\sum_i\sum_1^\infty
a_i^mt^{m-1}=\frac{a_1}{1-a_1t}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{1-a_nt}$$
which isn't the LHS. So, what should the LHS be?

Comment: I also got to this point but it is a exercise in university so I guess, it must be true.

Comment: Why **must** it be true?

Comment: It says: Proof that the following equation is correct.

Comment: Okay. Sorry you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $B=E_n - tA$ and use the [formula for the derivative of $\log\det$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579770/matrix-identity-involving-trace/1580544#1580544)
$$
d_t(\log\det B_t) =\operatorname{trace}\left(B_t^{-1}\;dB_t\right),
$$

Insert $dB_t=-A$ and adapt [the Neumann series formula for the inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972992/looking-for-a-reference-to-a-proof-of-i-a-1-i-a-a2-a3-ldots) (replace $A$ with $tA$): $$(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^{2}+A^{3}+\ldots$$